# Imagemapster reolocation of the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, i have been testing the ImageMapster plugin on an image. However, i wanted the tooltips (or the information panel) for each of those area tags to be right next to each other. > http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/eQCL6/

Currently, the information on when you hover over the black image reside on the left hand middle on each of the area tags. Is there anyway i can move each of those boxes next to each of the area panel.

I tried to implement the follow http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/ (please hover over the green pepper dip). This is what i tried:

```
image.mapster('set_options', { 
   areas: [{
     key: "dip",
     toolTip: newToolTip
   }]
});
```

Can someone help me implement the tooltip or just move the information boxes in accordance to their area tags.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you try setting up your actual code in a jsfiddle instead of referencing those examples? There's a lot of extra code going on there that you probably don't need, and I'm not exactly sure what you want to do since I'm not looking at your code but at the example code.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for replying, this is my actually code: http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/eQCL6/ but i need implementing a tooltip. However, it keeps breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe try this other code http://jsfiddle.net/gCTcF/62/
If you replace the two image with transparent png and place one over another with css z-depht you could achieve it. (It comes from another example from plugin autor)

```
            onMouseover: function (data) {
                inArea = true;
                $('#beatles-caption-header').text($(this).attr("alt"));
                $('#beatles-caption').show();
            },
            onMouseout: function (data) {
                inArea = false;
                $('#beatles-caption').hide();
            }
```